# Bluetooth stopping main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, bluetooth

I have an iOS 8 application that I'm using to transfer data via bluetooth from 1 device to another.

I have all of the services and characteristics working and can do the actual transfer.

I've tried to push the central manager onto another thread, but the UI on the central side locks up until the transfer is completed. When I look in instruments, I see thread 1 just get nailed.

I've tried this, but is hasn't seemed to work...

```
[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)];
```

What is the correct way to toss the `CBManager` into the background, so that it is not gumming up the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying a queue when you initialise `CBCentralManager` will deliver `CBCentralManager` delegate events on that queue, but your data transfer is performed by `CBPeripheral` methods.  You should explicitly dispatch your calls to `writeValue` on the background thread

Comment: do you mean put this method in the background and if so can you give me any ideas or pointers?

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error

Comment: You can't change how that method is invoked, but if you are doing work inside that method which is time consuming then you can dispatch it onto a background thread. Without seeing more of your code it is hard to offer advice as to where you are blocking the main thread